# Derivative of Squared Frobenius Norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Lets say I have an $n \times n$ matrix $a$ and I need to compute
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} h(a) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left\|a\right\|_\text{fro}^2 =
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \sum_{i,j} \left(a_{i,j}\right)^2 \text.
$$
I'm getting a result that cannot be right. **What am I doing wrong?** I start by rewriting the above term using $J_i$ to denote a column vector with $\left(J_i\right)_k = 0\ \forall i \neq k$ and $\left(J_i\right)_k = 1$ for $i = k$:
$$
= \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(J_i^\mathrm T a J_j\right)^2
$$
Now I apply the chain rule:
$$
= \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} u(v(a))
= \sum_{i,j} u'(v(a))\ v'(a)
= \sum_{i,j} \underbrace{2 J_i^\mathrm T a J_j}_{u'(v(a))}\ \underbrace{J_i^\mathrm T J_j}_{v'(a)}
$$
And this obviously resolves to:
$$
= \sum_{i,j} 2 J_i^\mathrm T a J_j \left[i=j\right]
= \sum_{i} 2 J_i^\mathrm T a J_i
= \sum_{i} 2 a_{i,i}
= 2\ \mathrm{tr}\left(a\right)
$$
Now I think that this **cannot be right** because this result implies that changing a non-diagonal element of $a$ won't change the value $h(a)$. But this contradicts the definition of $h$ above.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Quick note: this computation is made easier by noting that $h(a) = \operatorname{trace}(a^Ta)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I've added some clarifications, does your comment still apply?

Comment: Yes, my comment still applies.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks, than I also get $2\mathrm{tr}(a)$ for the result, which means that my computations are correct and my implications are wrong...

Comment: I agree with your implications and disagree with your results.  I think that you are taking matrix derivatives incorrectly.

Comment: See the note given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities)

Comment: If you calculate this correctly, you should end up with 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} h(a) = a^T
$$
or
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} h(a) = a
$$
depending on your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is assuming that you can apply the "product rule" and "chain rule" to matrix differentiation as you're thinking about it, as is stated in the article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities).

There is a "product rule" and "chain rule" that work in this context.  However, understanding them requires that you acknowledge that the derivative of $h(a)$ is *not* simply a scalar-valued function on matrices; rather, at each $a$, $h'(a)$ is a linear functional on matrices, which can be represented nicely as a matrix with the correct choice of dual basis.